# Fresh installation of Android Studio on Mac OS X produces OpenGL errors

Tags: android-studio

I am iOS guy who wants to take a look at how things are done on Android side.

I've just installed Android Studio on my Mac OS 10.10 and created test application using "Blank Activity" template. I've tried to launch it and now I'm seeing a bunch of logs about something going wrong there:

```
03-15 17:43:59.506    2323-2323/com.example.stanislaw.testapp I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-15 17:43:59.644    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-15 17:43:59.645    2323-2323/com.example.stanislaw.testapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa684e510, tid 2323
03-15 17:43:59.652    2323-2323/com.example.stanislaw.testapp D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-15 17:43:59.679    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa684e660, tid 2338
03-15 17:43:59.711    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 17:43:59.741    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-15 17:43:59.788    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 17:43:59.789    2323-2338/com.example.stanislaw.testapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa681fc60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Details:

I am using default Emulator suggested by Android Studio:

Emulator Nexus 5 Android 5.0.1 (API 21)

---

Googling for these errors didn't reveal anything meaningful to me so I would be thankful for any insights on why initial blank template on fresh Android Studio installation is not working (compared to Xcode where similar test app usually just works without any additional efforts).

Comment: Is it actually not working? The logcat output only shows some debug and warning messages. I don't see anything suggesting that something serious went wrong. Also, it looks like you're trying to run this on the emulator? If yes, you may want to specify that in the question.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, actually it didn't work when I was writing this - Emulator appeared with "Upgrading Android/Staging apps..." and then hanged on lock screen. Then after I did restart my machine/Studio, app started to launch with "Hello world!" label as expected. However I am still confused to see log strings like: "not implemented", "Failed to set" with "error=EGL_SUCCESS" which is never the case on iOS/Xcode blank template projects. I'll update my question with emulator version (I just picked what AS suggested me as default).

Comment: Are you sure it is ok to see these messages while doing Android development? I found similar question with suggestion to OMG reinstall windows to get rid of these warnings.